# Translate ARB assembly to GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to translate some old OpenGL code to modern OpenGL.  This code is reading data from a texture and displaying it.  The fragment shader is currently created using [`ARB_fragment_program`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_fragment_program.txt) commands:

```
static const char *gl_shader_code =
"!!ARBfp1.0\n"
"TEX result.color, fragment.texcoord, texture[0], RECT; \n"
"END";

GLuint program_id;
glGenProgramsARB(1, &program_id);
glBindProgramARB(GL_FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_ARB, program_id);
glProgramStringARB(GL_FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_ARB, GL_PROGRAM_FORMAT_ASCII_ARB, (GLsizei) strlen(gl_shader_code ), (GLubyte *) gl_shader_code );
```

I'd simply like to translate this into GLSL code.  I think the fragment shader should look something like this:

```
    #version 430 core
    uniform sampler2DRect s;

    void main(void) 
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2DRect(s, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0);
    }
```

But I'm not sure of a couple of details:

1. Is this the right usage of `texture2DRect`?
2. Is this the right usage of `gl_FragCoord`?

The texture is being fed with a pixel buffer object using `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you can just use the standard `sampler2D` instead of `sampler2DRect` (if you do not have a real need for it) since, quoting [the wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rectangle_Texture), "From a modern perspective, they (rectangle textures) seem essentially useless.".

You can then change your `texture2DRect(...)` to `texture(...)` or `texelFetch(...)` (to mimic your rectangle fetching).

2. Since you seem to be using OpenGL 4, you do not need to (should not ?) use `gl_FragColor` but instead declare an `out` variable and write to it.

Your fragment shader should look something like this in the end:

```
#version 430 core
uniform sampler2D s;
out vec4 out_color;

void main(void) 
{
    out_color = texelFecth(s, vec2i(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zouch, thank you very much for your response.  I took it and worked on this for a bit.  My final cores were very similar to what you suggested.  For the record the final vertex and fragment shaders I implemented were as follows:

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec2 UV;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);
    UV = vertexUV;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 UV;

out vec3 color; 

uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;

void main()
{
    color = texture2D(myTextureSampler, UV).rgb; 
}
```

That seemed to work.

Comment: Glad it works. Please note that the `texture2D` function is deprecated in OpenGL 3.3, you should use the `texture` function instead (same signature)